# Trying to pass parameters to HTML page in C# webView2

Tags: javascript, c#, html, wpf

I am attempting to navigate to an HTML file using parameters for location (lat and long)
This is a WPF application that has a built in browser which shows data from the google maps api.
I want to instantiate my map given the location parameters in C#

I read this thread:
[How to pass information from a WPF app to an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56297596/how-to-pass-information-from-a-wpf-app-to-an-html-page)
but I still get file not found. The url works fine without the parameters

```
    String sURL = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\html\\mapview.html";
    Uri uri = new Uri(sURL+"?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng+"");
    webBrowser1.Source = uri;
```

Any ideas as to why im getting these errors?

Not allowed to load local resource

and

ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: You can't pass parameters query string parameters to a static HTML page. It's the web server that is responsible for reading the query parameters.

Comment: @mm8 interesting, I hadn't thought of that. A workaround I used was to dynamically edit the page's source code before navigating to it. Would there be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

As mm8 pointed out, because I'm not using a web server it is not possible to pass parameters to my local file.

Reading various threads I had found a solution of installing a local webserver to the project, but since I didn't want to have to configure the web server and add unnecessary load to my projects, I worked around the issue by dynamically changing the coordinates in the HTML file before loading it in

```
        private void LoadMap()
        {
            // Before loading map, change the trojan horse coordinates to the latest ones by editing the html file
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(sURL);
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                if (lines[i].Contains("var lat"))
                {
                    lines[i] = "<script>var lat = " + lat + "; var lng = " + lng + ";</script>";
                    break;
                }
            }
            File.WriteAllLines(sURL, lines);
            // We can now load in the desired coordinates
            Uri uri = new Uri(sURL);
            webBrowser1.Source = uri;
        }
```

Note that this will require a new page load each time, but it is a good solution for changing things that need to be done on page load.

Another thing I tested was calling the script asynchronously. This also worked pretty well

```
        // we need to wait for map initialization (page load) before running our calcRoute script
        private async void NavMapLoading() //starts loading content asynchronously
        {
            await webBrowser1.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
            webBrowser1.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded += OnWebViewDOMContentLoaded;
            Uri uri = new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "html\\map_route.html");
            webBrowser1.Source = uri;
        }
        private async void OnWebViewDOMContentLoaded(object sender, CoreWebView2DOMContentLoadedEventArgs arg)
        {
            webBrowser1.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded -= OnWebViewDOMContentLoaded;
            webBrowser1.Focus();
            // now we can load destination
            await webBrowser1.ExecuteScriptAsync("calcRoute("+origin+","+dest+");");
        }
```